# Tails and Surveilance?

Tags: security, tails, surveillance

Can the ISP provider know that we are running tails?
As we have bridges in tor-browser is there something like this in tails?
If so then how does it work?
Is there a solution to this vulnerabilty?

Comment: Linux uses TTL value of 64ms for each packet. ISP cannot tell that you are using Tails but they know that it's a Linux distro. If you don't use Tor bridges, they will come to know that you are using Tor which is more valuable information for them, not the OS.

Comment: TTL is measured in hops traveled through, not miliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the ISP provider know that we are running tails?

A careful network observer could make a good guess that you were using Tails, by observing network connection behaviour which is (more or less) unique to Tails and making an educated guess. This is covered in the [Tails Documentation](https://tails.boum.org/doc/about/fingerprint/index.en.html).

> As we have bridges in tor-browser is there something like this in tails?

When you start Tails, you can configure it to use bridges at the greeter. You will be given the same Tor Launcher window that Tor Browser provides. You can configure these through the additional options available at the Tails Greeter when it first starts.

> If so then how does it work?

The same as for Tor Browser. Tails doesn't support `meek`, but it does support obfs{2,3,4} and scramblesuit. You should prefer `obfs4` if you need to use a pluggable transport.

Tails also doesn't have "default" bridges like Tor Browser does, so you will need to supply your own from [BridgeDB](https://bridges.torproject.org/).